# how to add scrollview in custom uiview so that added uiview will scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

Below is my code which I am using from a custom view referred from

[PeriscommentView](https://github.com/yoavlt/PeriscommentView)

However I want to show the entire cells and user can able to scroll, I have unhide the cells by commenting some codes however I don't know how to add a scrollview to this view so that cells added to it can be scrolled.

```
import UIKit

public class PeriscommentView: UIView {

private var visibleCells: [PeriscommentCell] = []
private var config: PeriscommentConfig

convenience override init(frame: CGRect) {
    let config = PeriscommentConfig()
    self.init(frame: frame, config: config)
}

required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.config = PeriscommentConfig()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

init(frame: CGRect, config: PeriscommentConfig) {
    self.config = config
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

override public func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?) {
    super.willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    self.backgroundColor = config.layout.backgroundColor
}

public func addCell(cell: PeriscommentCell) {
    cell.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height), size: cell.frame.size)
    visibleCells.append(cell)
    self.addSubview(cell)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.config.appearDuration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        let dy = cell.frame.height + self.config.layout.cellSpace
        for c in self.visibleCells {
            let origin = c.transform
            let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -dy)
            c.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(origin, transform)
        }
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.config.disappearDuration, delay: self.config.appearDuration, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
       // cell.alpha = 0.0
    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
       // cell.removeFromSuperview()
       // self.visibleCells.removeAtIndex(self.visibleCells.indexOf(cell)!)
    }
}

public func addCell(profileImage: UIImage, name: String, comment: String) {
    let rect = CGRect.zero
    let cell = PeriscommentCell(frame: rect, profileImage: profileImage, name: name, comment: comment, config: self.config)

    self.addCell(cell)
}

}
```

I have tried editing the code and its floating the views however I don't want it I want to have a proper scroll.

**EDITED CODE**

```
import UIKit

public class PeriscommentView: UIView {

private var visibleCells: [PeriscommentCell] = []
private var config: PeriscommentConfig

var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var containerView = UIView()

convenience override init(frame: CGRect) {
    let config = PeriscommentConfig()
    self.init(frame: frame, config: config)
    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, self.bounds.height)
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:600, height: 1200)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.bounds.height, left:  0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)


    containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 1000)

    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    self.addSubview(scrollView)
}

required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.config = PeriscommentConfig()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, self.bounds.height)
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:600, height: 1200)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.bounds.height, left:  0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)

    //self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -100.0)


    containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 1000)

    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    self.addSubview(scrollView)
}
init(frame: CGRect, config: PeriscommentConfig) {
    self.config = config
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, self.bounds.height)
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:600, height: 1200)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.bounds.height, left:  0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)


    //self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -100.0)


    containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 1000)

    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    self.addSubview(scrollView)

}

override public func willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: UIView?) {
    super.willMoveToSuperview(newSuperview)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    self.backgroundColor = config.layout.backgroundColor
}

public func addCell(cell: PeriscommentCell) {
    cell.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height), size: cell.frame.size)
    visibleCells.append(cell)
    self.containerView.addSubview(cell)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.config.appearDuration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        let dy = cell.frame.height + self.config.layout.cellSpace
        for c in self.visibleCells {
            let origin = c.transform
            let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -dy)
            c.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(origin, transform)
        }
        }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.config.disappearDuration, delay: self.config.appearDuration, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
        // cell.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (Bool) -> Void in
            // cell.removeFromSuperview()
            // self.visibleCells.removeAtIndex(self.visibleCells.indexOf(cell)!)
    }
}

public func addCell(profileImage: UIImage, name: String, comment: String) {
    let rect = CGRect.zero
    let cell = PeriscommentCell(frame: rect, profileImage: profileImage, name: name, comment: comment, config: self.config)

    self.addCell(cell)
}

}
```

Comment: uiview will never scroll, uiscrollview can scroll only, check content size if uiscrollview not scrolling. thanks

Comment: @JagveerSingh That is what I said na thats why I am trying to add a scrollview to this view and then to its container view I will add uiviews.. Please read the question!!